# How do I aggregate columns and calculate a cumulative sum in SQL (mutate() and cumsum() in R)

Tags: sql, cumulative-sum

The data looks like:

| road_id | count | centimeters |
| --- | --- | --- |
| road111 | 123 | 502 |
| road123 | 345 | 234 |
| road124 | 3256 | 23498 |

My aim is to calculate the "volume kilometers traffic", calculate a percentage of each row, order by the count, and calculate the cumulative sum. I know how to do this in R, but struggle to reproduce in SQL.

To achieve this, my code in R is (it works properly):

```
data_perc <- data %>% 
             mutate(kilometers = centimeters/100000) %>%
             mutate(vkt = count*kilometers) %>%
             mutate(vktperc = vkt/sum(vkt)) %>%
             arrange(desc(count)) %>%
             mutate(vktcumsum = cumsum(vktperc))
```

In SQL, I tried this but had error:

```
select road_id, count, geom, centimeters/100000 as kilometers, cap1.y as vkt, cap2.z as vktperc, sum(vktperc) as vktcumsum
from roaddata rd1
inner join roaddata rd2 on rd1.road_id >= rd2.road_id
cross apply (select count*kilometers as product) cap1(y)
cross apply (select (vkt/sum(vkt))*100 as percentage) cap2(z)
group by road_id, count
order by count desc;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.  For instance, what do you want the cumulative sum of?  What do you want the percentage of? 
 Also tag with the database you are using..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
select rd.*,
       centimeters / 100000 as kilometers, 
       count * centimeters / 100000 as vkt,
       ( sum(count * centimeters / 100000) over (order by count) /
         sum(count * centimeters / 100000) over ()
       ) as vktcumsum      
from roaddata rd;
```

But without the results and a clear explanation (not code!) it is hard to know if this is really what you are trying to do.